# ldconfig can't find lib in standard location

Tags: linux, centos, shared-libraries

EDIT:

Cloudera says that CentOS is supported please check [Cloudera manual install](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_noncm_installation.html) as they have instructions on how to do so, it relies on libpython2.6.so.1.0 and libsasl2.so.2.

---

When installing a package ( impala from cloudera repository ) I am told that libsasl2.so.2 and libpython2.6.so.1.0 are missing. After some searching people have said that soft linking the more up to date versions is fine.

I do this in the same folder that all other libs are which is /usr/lib64. However, when I run ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib64 I do not see the new libs in the list. I run the following commands:

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
ln -s /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3 /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2
ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib64
```

I have looked at other questions, but none of the answers solve the issue. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: »»  When installing a package «« : Which package is it about ?

Comment: impala from cloudera repository

Comment: try to update cache with `ldconfig -p`

Comment: Still only shows the older libs.

Comment: »»Cloudera says that CentOS is supported«« : The packages are for CentOS 6 , and your OS is CentOS 7  ......... ( CentOS 5 packages are also available.)

Comment: Thanks Knud. Do you mind writing that as an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> Cloudera says that CentOS is supported

The packages are for CentOS 6 , and your OS is CentOS **7** .....

.... ( CentOS 5 packages are also available.)

---